# Graph query using AQL

Tags: graph, arangodb, aql

I have 3 collections, 1st one is the list (vertices), 2nd one is the users (vertices) and the third one is the activity (edges). I plan to store any kind of activity done on a list in the activity collection (such as like, comment, flag and so on).
suppose I need to fetch all lists of any user along with the count of each event on every list he created, like no of like like, comments, flag on each list in a single query. How do I do that?
I have been exploring arangodb docs for like 2 days but can't figure out how to write such query.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each individual activity is represented as an edge between both of your vertex collections, then find a user, retrieve its neighbors (the list vertices) and group the edges by type (an edge attribute?):

```
FOR u IN users
  FILTER u._key == "john"
  FOR v, e IN 1..1 OUTBOUND u activities
    // v is a list vertex document
    // e is an activity edge document
    COLLECT list = v._id, type = e.type, user = u._id
    WITH COUNT INTO count
    RETURN { list, user, type, count }
```

The result with my test data:

```
list        | user       | type    | count
------------|------------|---------|------
lists/john1 | users/john | comment | 1
lists/john1 | users/john | modify  | 3
lists/john1 | users/john | vote    | 1
lists/john2 | users/john | delete  | 1
lists/john2 | users/john | like    | 1
lists/john2 | users/john | modify  | 2
lists/john2 | users/john | vote    | 2
```

If you want to keep the list and user document, you could do:

```
FOR u IN users
  FILTER u._key == "john"
  FOR v, e IN 1..1 OUTBOUND u activities
    COLLECT list = v._id, type = e.type
    AGGREGATE count = LENGTH(1) INTO groups
    RETURN {
        list: groups[0].v,
        user: groups[0].u,
        type,
        count
    }
```

For large amounts of data the following might use less memory because it avoids keeping track of groups and looks up the necessary documents instead:

```
FOR u IN users
  FILTER u._key == "john"
  FOR v, e IN 1..1 OUTBOUND u activities
    COLLECT list_id = v._id, user_id = u._id, type = e.type
    WITH COUNT INTO count
    RETURN {
        list: DOCUMENT(list_id),
        user: DOCUMENT(user_id),
        type,
        count
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for replying this late but how do I find one particular vertex, If there is more than one neighboring vertex.

Comment: Which vertex would that be?

Comment: Hi, I think this query will give me all lists made by John that is what I want, but this query will not give me counts of all activities made by other users on a list made by John, such like, flag counts. It would be very helpful for me If you can represent this scenario on a graph.

Comment: Using above query will only get me all lists of John as because of this clause 1..1 traversal depth will be up to level 1. with this query, all neighboring vertex of user John will be selected and all edges connecting user John with neighboring vertex will be selected. I do not think that with this query I will get counts of all activities done on neighboring vertex by another user.

Comment: Could you please add a visual representation of your graph to the question? It's not clear to me how edges of other users point to lists. I can't give you any advice without seeing the actual data.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question with the scenario. Above image says that user 1 has reviewed the place, user 2 has liked that review and user 3 has commented on that review.

Comment: Do you actually reference the edge between User1 and Place like a vertex with the other two edges? While this is possible, there is no special handling of edges pointing to edges. The edges you point to will be treated like vertices. You could take the `User1->Place` edge as starting point (like a vertex) for another traversal for inbound connections (the other two edges). If you want to avoid having multiple traversals like that, then you will have to define additional entities that translate to vertices, like `User1->Review1->Place`.

Comment: First I need to find total reviews of any user and then loop on that to get like count and comment count. Is this is what you are suggesting

Comment: Well, with your current data model you will have to do two traversals to retrieve all three edges from your example. Then you can process interaction counts as you wish.

Comment: This is query I have come up with   FOR p IN places
  FILTER p.place_id == "MMI000"
    FOR vertex, edge, path IN 1..2 ANY p relation return edge.type , But in this query how do I find count of likes and comments on each review.

Comment: I have updated my question with the final scenario and my query of approach, how do I find comment and like count on each review

Comment: Hi, this is the final query I have up with  `FOR p IN places
  FILTER p.place_id == "MMI000"
    FOR vertex, edge, path IN 1..1 INBOUND p relation
        LET likeCount = LENGTH(FOR ivertex, iedge, ipath IN 1..1 INBOUND vertex relation FILTER iedge.type == 'like' RETURN 1)
        LET flagCount = LENGTH(FOR ivertex, iedge, ipath IN 1..1 INBOUND vertex relation FILTER iedge.type == 'flag' RETURN 1)
        RETURN {likeCount:likeCount, review: DOCUMENT(vertex._id), flagCount:flagCount}`.  Just need to know If i can optimize it further or not

Comment: Try to avoid multiple identical traversals with different post-filters. It should be more efficient to traverse just once for like and flag count: `LET counts = MERGE(FOR ivertex, iedge IN 1..1 INBOUND vertex relation COLLECT type = iedge.type WITH COUNT INTO count RETURN { [type]: count }) RETURN { likeCount: counts.like, flagCount: counts.flag }`